# Converting the text into a clickable Link

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, url, clickable

I have a web application, which displays the result parsed from an XML file in the form of table using ajax. It is working good, but the thing is, the data in the XML file is mostly URLs but I am seeing the result in the form of text. I want that text to be made/converted into a clickable link so that it would make my life easier. Is there any code which would make it possible? If yes, please let me know where should I place it. That code is in ASPX page which also has the html code which is responsible for the style of my webpage..

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var CheckImage = "<img src='images/check.png' height='25' width='25'>";
    var CrossImage = "<img src='images/cross.png' height='25' width='25'>";
    var Fail = "<img src='images/fail.png' height='25' width='30'>";
    setInterval(url, 100);
    setInterval(redirects, 100);
    function url()
    {
     $.ajax(
            {

                url: "/XMLFile.xml",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                cache: false,
                success: function (xml)
                {

                    var tableContent1 = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>" +
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<th>SiteName</th>" +
                        "<th>URLType</th>" +
                        "<th>DNSStatus</th>" +
                        "<th>TargetStatus</th>" +
                        "<th>TTL</th>" +
                        "<th>SSL</th>" +
                        "<th>Force</th>" +
                        "</tr>";

                    $(xml).find('ProdURL').each(function ()
                    {

                        tableContent1 += "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('ProdHost') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('URLType') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('DNSStatus') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('TargetStatus') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('TTL') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('SSL') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('Force') + "</td>" +                           
                            "</tr>";
                    });

                    tableContent1 += "</table>";
                    $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent1)
                    getdata(tableContent1);
                }    
            });         
    }  
    function redirects()
    {
       //this ajax code parses the information from XML file and displays it on the table
        $.ajax(
            {
               //If the name of the XML file is changed, make sure to update that in the url:
                url: "/XMLFile.xml",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType:"url",
                cache: false,
                success: function (xml)
                {


                var tableContent2 = "<table border='5' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='10'>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<th>URL</th>" +
                "<th>Target</th>" +
                "<th>Status</th>" +
                "</tr>";

                    $(xml).find('Redirect').each(function ()
                    {
                        tableContent2 += "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('URL')+ "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + $(this).attr('Target') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + ($(this).attr('Status') == "Fail" ? Fail : CheckImage && $(this).attr('Status') == "OK" ? CheckImage : CrossImage) + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";

                    });

                    tableContent2 += "</table>";
                    $("#UpdatePanel1").html(tableContent2)
                    getdata(tableContent2);

                }

            });
    }
```

Comment: you may convert an url address into an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: @gaetanoM I didn't understand. Where should I put it?

Comment: in your server side  I assume

Comment: may you add the ajax returned value in your question?

Comment: @gaetanoM I have updated my question

Comment: if you refers to **$(this).attr('URL')** the solutions is: '<td><a href="' + $(this).attr('URL') + ">' + $(this).attr('URL')+ '</a></td>'

Comment: @gaetanoM , it did not work.. :/

Comment: @LakshitSharma can you explain why that didn't work? what is happening instead? Does the value of `$(this).attr('URL')` actually hold the URL you want to be a link?

Comment: I think a `'` was missing from the example. You can try:  `'<td><a href="' + $(this).attr('URL') + '">' + $(this).attr('URL')+ '</a></td>'`

Comment: @AndrewLohr, it worked little bit, but my other result is being affected.. I'm not able to see them there

Comment: @AndrewLohr, just focus on the redirects section of my ajax code. That one part from which it is parsing values, has the actual URLs..

Comment: I don't know what "my other results is being affected" or "it worked a little bit" means. You need to explain what is happening for further help

Comment: @AndrewLohr.. Alright. Can you look at the last line of the 'Redirects' ajax code? It says for the attribute 'Status',. the result which I was getting for that, has vanished. And tried the same code for the second line which has the attribute  ''target", it doesn't show anything for that too (neither text nor link).. It just showed for the first attribute.. And  those converted link doesn't actually work, i mean it just acts as an empty button or something like that. It does redirects or opens new page or something

Comment: @AndrewLohr, hey it is working now.. it was just a '+' sign that i was missing in the end.. Thanks for your help and time brother :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more complete example to show you. This is adding a anchor tag with the URL inside your table when you are creating your `<td>` in the loop.

```js
let tableContent2 = "";

$("div").each(function() {
  tableContent2 += "<tr>" +
    "<td> <a href='" + $(this).attr('URL') + "'>" + $(this).attr('URL') + "</a></td>" +
    "<td>" + $(this).attr('Target') + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + $(this).attr('Status') + "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
})

$("#UpdatePanel1").html(tableContent2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this div is just for this example -->
<div URL="https://example.com" Target="I am a target" Status="OK"></div>

<table>
  <tbody id="UpdatePanel1">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It is working now, earlier I was missing a '+' sign in the end.. that is why I was not able to see the other things..

Comment: A step further if you wanted to clean the code up you could use Template Literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals but keep in mind theres no support for them in IE

Comment: Alright, Thanks again.. Thanks for your time and help :)